React Native - Current Activity is of incorrect class, expected AppCompatActivity, received MyActivity
I need to call react native screen when I get a silent notification, currently I am experimenting with Phone State, I does this using PhoneStateListenr class that trigger Second Activity named MyActivity that run React Native Code inside it.
When the MyActivity class is ran I got following error, that is Stating that Current Activity is of incorrect class,
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current Activity is of incorrect class, expected AppCompatActivity, received MyActivity

MyActivity triggers on Phone state,
package com.apartmentapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class PhoneStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            final Context ctx;
            ctx = context;

            final Intent intnt = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);

            intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            intnt.putExtra("phone_no", "9876543210");
            intnt.putExtra("contact_name", "Test User");

            intnt.putExtra("id", "1234");

            ctx.startActivity(intnt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


Below is MyActivityClass
package com.apartmentapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.common.LifecycleState;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.List;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private Window wind;
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SoLoader.init(this, false);

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(getApplication()).getPackages();

        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setCurrentActivity(this)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .addPackages(packages)
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .setJavaScriptExecutorFactory(new HermesExecutorFactory())
                .build();

        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "AlertPopupFragment", null);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        FrameLayout alertPopUpFragment = findViewById(R.id.alertPopUpFragment);

        alertPopUpFragment.addView(mReactRootView);
    }

    private Bundle getLaunchOptions(String message) {
        Bundle initialProperties = new Bundle();
        initialProperties.putString("message", message);
        return initialProperties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        wind = this.getWindow();
        wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {

    }
}


I also tried to solve it by setting MyActivity as MainActivity,
here MyActivity defined in Android Manifest file
<activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:taskAffinity=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MyActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Please provide solution

The error is quite clear what the problem is and how to solve it:
Current Activity is of incorrect class, expected AppCompatActivity, received MyActivity
At the moment your definition is MyActivity extends Activity, but react Native seems to require to to change it to MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity.
The full class name of AppCompatActivity is most likely androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity. So you will have to add an import at the beginning of the Java file:
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 

